# How to remove the parental lock on an Xbox 360 when you've forgotten the password?

Tags: xbox-360

I've turned 13, and My dad forgot the password to parental lock control on my Xbox 360.  How can it be removed?

Comment: I'm going to assume good faith here, i.e., that OP isn't just looking for a way to change the settings so he can play RDR2.

Comment: I'll also assume good faith, but I'll leave this warning just in case: if OP really is trying to bypass parental control to play restricted games, his father will eventually notice. Either he'll catch OP playing restricted games, or he'll be wondering why the passcode has changed. If that happens, he might very well restrict OP's freedom even more than he already does. Whether playing RDR2 for 2 hours is worth not being able to play anything else for the next 3 months, is not for me to say.

Comment: @Studoku RDR2 isn't on 360.

Answer (score 3):

Your dad can reset the passcode by answering the secret question from when he set up the controls. To do this, enter an incorrect code and one of the options will be to reset the passcode. Answer the secret question and enter a new code.

If your dad has also forgotten the secret question, it gets a little trickier. If the console is registered to an adult's account in their name, log into that and select it from devices. You can reset the code there.

If not, you (that is to say your dad) will need to contact [Xbox Support](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/browse/xbox-360?xr=shellnav)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to contact Xbox Customer Support for your issue.

Xbox Customer Support US&Canada

1-800-469-9269.